# parse.com - Parse.Cloud.httpRequest doesn't return Hebrew characters

Tags: parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get hebrew characters returning after using Parse.Cloud.httpRequest:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFromPro", function(request, response) {
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'http://www...",
    method:'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    // success
    response.success(httpResponse.text);
},function(httpResponse) {
    // error
    response.error("not ok");
});
});
```

but I'm getting things like:

\"bizName\":\"××§×¦××¢× ×× ××××××\"

\"bizName\":\"×¦×××ª ×× - ×××§×¦××¢× ×× ××××××!\"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure what returns from your url is definitely in UTF-8 format not something like UTF-16LE or iso-8859-8. Also make sure that the problem stems from your cloud code function rather than a display issue on your client. To test that call you function via REST API and test the returning charterers in terminal.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I've tested my function via REST API, and still got the same "jibrish" response. and yes the currect content-type is UTF-8.

Comment: Instead of returning raw text with httpResponse.text can you try httpResponse.data instead ?

Comment: Parse returning httpResponse object which contains only 'text' and not 'data'

Comment: Can you inspect the `httpResponse.headers` property to see what is the content-type of the response object is ?

Comment: Accept-Ranges: "bytes"
Age: "0"
Cache-Control: "private"
Connection: "keep-alive"
Content-Length: "1529"
Content-Type: "text/html; Charset=UTF-8"
Date: "Fri, 16 Oct 2015 16:21:59 GMT"
Expires: "Sun, 31 Dec 1989 22:00:00 GMT"
Set-Cookie: "ASPSESSIONIDAASRCRSR=GFNNMNIALPPEIBPPDBGHOOIP; path=/"
Via: "1.1 varnish, 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.19)"
X-Cache: "MISS from localhost"
X-Cache-Lookup: "MISS from localhost:3128"
X-Powered-By: "ASP.NET"
X-Varnish: "1012223741

Comment: As I looked at the responses you got, I now realised it is in fact UTF-8 byte array, you need to convert it to a string. Try [this](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder) UTF-8 decoder. You can see all the Hebrew characters

Comment: Thanks! I've used:                        var decoded = decodeURIComponent(escape(response.text)).  Thanks again! :)